# App rejected due to Performance - App Completeness

Tags: ios, facebook, appstore-approval

> Your app or its metadata does not appear to include final content. Specifically, your app appears to be in development mode when we attempted to login with a Facebook account.

My app has just been rejected for the second time in iTunes Connect. They have told me it's specifically due to app being in development mode when logging with a Facebook account. I can rectify this. However, they have sent me a screenshot which has got me confused. It shows nothing about logging in with Facebook.

So I wanted to ask if it's only the Facebook login I need to fix or they might also want me to fix some other stuff which I don't know about?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only truthful answer anyone can give you is "I don't know". You for sure need to fix your Facebook login, but after you fix that Apple Review may come back and say there was another issue. Apple review doesn't always mention all the issues in the app on the first review. I've also seen them throw in seemingly meaningless screenshots, so that screenshot may or may not be relevant.

If you have a question, I would suggest that you ask the reviewer by replying to the rejection notice in the Resolution Center. You can find the Resolution Center by clicking on the "unresolved iOS issue" link under your app in iTunesConnect.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I will endeavour to fix it and resubmit again